# adjust the width of the caption to the width of a table

Tags: tables, captions, floatrow

there are probably many questions similar to the one I have mentioned
[Url 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493160/how-to-make-caption-width-of-a-table-equal-to-the-width-of-a-table)
[Url 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343526/move-left-aligned-table-caption-synchronous-with-table)

but it turns out that it doesn't work in my case, I've read the **floatrow** documentation and the `\FBwidth` command caught my attention but I don't know how to use it. Below I present an example, the objective is that table 1 is the same as table 2 with respect to the title "fits the width of the table and its alignment in the center"

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm, right=2.5cm,headheight=1cm,showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{bookmark, amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol,multirow,booktabs, array}
\usepackage{threeparttable, longtable}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[longtable]{LTcapwidth=table}
\floatsetup[table]{position=top}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{spaced}{\\[2ex]}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig. ,labelsep=newline, parskip=1.5cm}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=newline,font=normalsize,textfont=it, labelfont={bf}, parskip=2ex,justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{document}
\section{An table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Cronbach alpha}
\label{tb:fiabilidad}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}\toprule
    \bfseries Scale & \bfseries Ítems &  $\pmb{\alpha}$\; \bfseries Cronbach \\ \midrule
    RPA &  20 & 0.8531 \\
    PCP* & 17 & 0.7645 \\ \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{*}Items 11, 15 and 16 . } \\
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\section{Another table}
\begin{longtable}[c]{lcc}
    \caption[Alpha Cronbach's]{Cronbach Alpha} \\ \toprule
\bfseries Scale &\bfseries Ítems & $\pmb{\alpha}$\; \bfseries Cronbach \\ \midrule \endfirsthead
\caption[]{(Continue)} \\ \toprule
\bfseries Variable &\bfseries N &\bfseries Frecuencia \\ \midrule \endhead \bottomrule
\endfoot \endlastfoot
Cronbach \\ \midrule
    RPA &  20 & 0.8531 \\
    PCP* & 17 & 0.7645 \\ \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{*}Items 11, 15 and 16 . } \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Objetive caption align width]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to use  `floatrow`. `\ttabbox` can use an optional argument to control the caption width. By default, it is set to `\FBwidth`, but you can choose a multiple of this value.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm, right=2.5cm,headheight=1cm,showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{bookmark, amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol,multirow,booktabs, array}
\usepackage{threeparttable, longtable}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[longtable]{LTcapwidth=table}
\floatsetup[table]{position=top}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{spaced}{\\[2ex]}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig. , labelsep=newline, parskip=1.5cm}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=newline,font=normalsize,textfont=it, labelfont={bf}, parskip=2ex,justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
    \ttabbox{\caption[Alpha Cronbach's]{Some rather long caption, with a nice lengthy addendum. }}
{\begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
\bfseries Scale &\bfseries Ítems & $\pmb{\alpha}$\; \bfseries Cronbach \\ \midrule
Cronbach \\ \midrule
    RPA & 20 & 0.8531 \\
    PCP* & 17 & 0.7645 \\ \bottomrule\addlinespace
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{*}Items 11, 15 and 16 . }
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: fantastic, i was skipping using `\ttabbox` but it turned out to fix my case. Thank you very much @Bernard

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I well understand your question. Try this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm, right=2.5cm,headheight=1cm,showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{bookmark, amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol,multirow,booktabs, array}
\usepackage{threeparttable, longtable}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[longtable]{LTcapwidth=table}
\floatsetup[table]{position=top}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{spaced}{\\[2ex]}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig. ,labelsep=newline, parskip=1.5cm}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=newline,font=normalsize,textfont=it, labelfont={bf}, parskip=2ex,justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{document}
    \section{A table}
    \begin{longtable}[c]{lcc}
            \caption[Alpha Cronbach's]{Cronbach Alpha} \\ 
            \begin{tabular}{lcc}\toprule
                \bfseries Scale & \bfseries Ítems &  $\pmb{\alpha}$\; \bfseries Cronbach \\ \midrule
                RPA &  20 & 0.8531 \\
                PCP* & 17 & 0.7645 \\ \bottomrule
                \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{*}Items 11, 15 and 16 . } \\
            \end{tabular}
            \label{tb:fiabilidad}
    \end{longtable}
    
    \section{Another table}
    \begin{longtable}[c]{lcc}
        \caption[Alpha Cronbach's]{Cronbach Alpha} \\ \toprule
        \bfseries Scale &\bfseries Ítems & $\pmb{\alpha}$\; \bfseries Cronbach \\ \midrule \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{(Continue)} \\ \toprule
        \bfseries Variable &\bfseries N &\bfseries Frecuencia \\ \midrule \endhead \bottomrule
        \endfoot \endlastfoot
        Cronbach \\ \midrule
        RPA &  20 & 0.8531 \\
        PCP* & 17 & 0.7645 \\ \bottomrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{*}Items 11, 15 and 16 . } \\
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: effectively I don't want to use longtable to wrap the caption